# Can we add two or multiple probabilities together when rolling two dices?

Tags: probability

Given that we have two dices (with 6 sides), rolling a `2` (1+1) or `12` (6+6) will give us a probability of `1/36` right?

When we want to know the probability of `2 AND 12` togetehr, can we then simply add the two probabilities, so that we will get a probability of `2/36`? Could that be?

Let’s think this further and let’s say we want to calculate the probability of `2, 3, 11, 12` together … do we then get a probability of `6/36` (1/36 + 2/36 + 2/36 + 1/36), which is the same like rolling a `7`? Does this make sense? My intuition tells me that summing up those 4 probability is not quite realistic, because `7` will always be rolled more often (statistically?), right!? No!?

I am not a math guy, but quite interested in this question. Thanks for giving me your expertise!

Comment: What does it mean to roll both a 2 *and* 12?

Comment: 2/36 would represent the probability of rolling either a 2 *or* 12.   Unless your dice exhibit quantum superposition, I'd wager rolling 2 *and* 12 has zero probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are interested in comparing the chances of getting a sum of $7$ or either one of $2,3,11$ or $12$ when rolling two dice, i.e. comparison of $P(7)$ and $P(2 \ \cup 3 \ \cup 11 \ \cup 12)$. When two dice are rolled, a particular sum can occur in following ways:

- **2: (1,1)**
- **3: (1,2);(2,1)**
- 4: (1,3);(2,2);(3,1)
- 5: (1,4);(2,3);(3,2);(4,1)
- 6: (1,5);(2,4);(3,3);(4,2);(5,1)
- **7: (1,6);(2,5);(3,4);(4,3);(5,2);(6,1)**
- 8: (2,6);(3,5);(4,4);(5,3);(6,2)
- 9: (3,6);(4,5);(5,4);(6,3)
- 10: (4,6);(5,5);(6,4)
- **11: (5,6);(6,5)**
- **12: (6,6)**

Getting a sum of 7 has the probability $P(7) = \frac{6}{36}$. Getting a sum as either of $2,3,11$ or $12$ has the probability $P(2 \ \cup 3 \ \cup 11 \ \cup 12) = \frac{1+2+2+1}{36} = \frac{6}{36}$. Your intuition that $7$ (as the sum) will always be rolled more often is right, but getting a sum of either $2,3,11,12$ is equally likely.